# If input is checked set parent background

Tags: html, css

My html markup looks like this..

```
<div class="siteCheckboxes">
   <label for="filterAll">
      All <input name="filterAll" type="checkbox" id="filterAll" checked="checked"  />
   </label>
</div>
```

I need to know how to change the color of the parent label the checkbox is in.
I have tried doing...

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked > label{ background-color:#F00; }
```

in order to change the parent labels background colour, but this does not work.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `>` is the child selector, i.e. it would search for `label` elements inside `input`.

Comment: Set the background when you render and then if the color status changes you change the background of the parent element with js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS cannot modify parents based on children. It is a one way path of `parent -> child` access.

-EDIT:

As Little Big Bot points out in the comments, there are sibling selectors (`+` and `~`) available but they are not fully supported yet. And they would not help you if you are nesting the elements as you state. In any case here they are:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

Comment: Not quite, you can access siblings with `~`. Not fully supported, though.

Comment: @LittleBigBot Edited to address siblings.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with strictly CSS. CSS (not even CSS 3) does not have a "parent" selector.

More info: http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: Ok i'll use `$('input:checkbox:checked').parent().css("background-color","#F00");` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS if you use markup where the `input` and `label` elements are adjacent siblings and not nested and the label appears after the checkbox (which is much more common usage and hence better usability):

```
<input name="filterAll" id="filterall" type="checkbox" id="filterAll" 
       checked="checked"  />
<label for="filterAll">All</label>
```

Then you can use the adjacent sibling selector `+`:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { background-color:#F00; }
```